# Python array caching vs C array caching

Tags: python, caching

Pretty inexperienced in Python and I realize this is awfully basic, but how well does Python cache blocks compared to C? For example, in C:

```
gridWidth = 100000
gridHeight = 100000

for (i=0; i<gridHeight; i++){

    for (j=0; j<gridWidth; j++){

       massiveNum += arr[i*gridWidth + j]
    }
}
```

is way faster than

```
  massiveNum += arr[i + j*gridWidth]
```

because the data is cached efficiently in the first.

If I'm going for the same speed in Python, can I do something as simple as

```
for i in range(0,gridHeight):

    for j in range(0,gridWidth):

       massiveNum += arr[i*gridWidth + j]
```

or is there some special thing I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

You question is moot. When you got a whole interpreter, boxed number types, heap allocations of said types, etc. between your code and the machine, cache efficency is the least of your worries. Since Python's built-in sequence types use (dynamic and over-allocating) C arrays under the hood, the same rules should apply, but there are two major caveats:

- There are a lot of "hidden" memory access for every Python operations (e.g. for type checking, variable and member lookup, creating "bound method" objects before calling methods, number coercion) in between that may reduce the benefit.
- In many cases (i.e. unless noted otherwise), all containers store references to boxed objects, so when you iterate a `list` of `int` objects, the CPU cache can only help with fetching these pointers faster, not with handling the objects behind those.

I'd be surprised if you could measure any difference as all. If you want to optimize, there are many things which are a thousand times more effective and far more obvious. Use built-ins, NumPy, write a bit of C, use Cython, or simply optimize your Python code.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question, didn't I?

Comment: @agf: Or I did ;) Though the difference between `arr[i + j*gridWidth]` and `arr[i*gridWidth + j]` seems familiar from CPU cache questions.

Comment: Nah, your interpretation makes _way_ more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Python *arrays*, then I would assume that they are laid out linear in memory, so yes, sequential access would be the most cache-friendly way to access them.

If you are talking about Python *lists*, I would think that there is no way that the python list and the objects in them are laid out in a linear fashion in memory. Since every item of the list can be of any type, it would at best look like an linear array of pointers - so actually accessing each item might jump all over memory.

Also the general overhead of Python might make any caching effect negligible.

You might also want to optimize the loop:

```
n = gridHeight * gridWidth
i = 0
while i < n:
    massiveNum += arr[i]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to consider using [numpy](https://numpy.org/) for operating multidimensional arrays in Python.

NumPy is written with pure C backend, so you won't suffer huge boxing-unboxing penalties of interpreted code. Then, *maybe*, you'll be at least able to measure cache performance, and use things like row-major vs column-major order, [strides](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) etc.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop uses `j` for the index, so your best cache performance will come when adjacent parts of the array are indexed by adjacent values of `j`. This is acheived by multiplying `i` instead of `j`.

Since your array is one dimensional this question is completely language agnostic - caching is handled by the processor, not the language. If you were using a two dimensional array you might get a different answer.